# Dragging widgets to window won't work

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt-creator

I'm using Qt Creator for several months now and from time to time, I get a problem dragging widgets like buttons, line edits and so from the toolbox to the window.

I try by removing the layouts but still get the same issue.

I use Qt Creator 2.4.0 on OS X 10.7.2

Thanks for helping

Comment: In what way does it not work, do the dragged items disappear before releasing? Do they appear in the wrong place?  Do they wreck your existing layout?

Comment: They just don't move at all when I try to drag from the widget box.

Comment: @spyke there is no code involved in this behavior it all happens in the form editor...

Comment: Try the workaround described in this link...http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8378

Comment: Thank you but I'm on OS X so that solution didn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this problem by upgrading Qt Creator to version 2.4.1 on OS X

The [solution](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/8378) described above by @spyke might also be helpful for Windows users.

It case there is a dead link, the solution for Windows says :

> I was using Qt Designer for Qt Jambi built with Qt 4.6.4 on Windows 7 ×64 when this problem occurred. After a while I realized that the problem was not only in Qt designer, but in Windows in general: Explorer, FileZilla and more.
>
> The solution was then found by searching for general Windows 7 drag and drop problems [answers.microsoft.com].
>
> In short: Select a file in Windows Explorer with click and hold left mouse button. While holding the button down, hit the Esc key. Then drag and drop starts working again.